# Passing data to props after asynchronous call in Vue

Tags: asynchronous, vue.js, vue-component

I have set up a bare bones vue project to show the problem. The only thing I added was the axios package. The problem is when I try to set the property of child component after an asynchronous call I cant read that property in the component. If you look at the code you can see I console log several times to show when I can get the data and when I cant. Please help me figure out what im missing here.

Parent

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <HelloWorld :test_prop="testData" :test_prop2="testData2" :test_prop3="testData3" test_prop4="I work also"/>
    <div>{{testData5}}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  data() {
    return {
      testData: '',
      testData2: 'I work just fine',
      testData3: '',
      testData5: ''
    }
  },
  created: function(){
    var self = this;
    this.testDate3 = 'I dont work';
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/42').then(function(response){
      //I need this one to work
      self.testData = 'I dont work either';

      self.testData5 = 'I work also';
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

Child

```
<template>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: ['test_prop', 'test_prop2', 'test_prop3', 'test_prop4'],
  data() {
    return {
      comp_data: this.test_prop,
      comp_data2: this.test_prop2,
      comp_data3: this.test_prop3,
      comp_data4: this.test_prop4
    }
  },
  created: function(){
    console.log(this.test_prop);
    console.log(this.test_prop2);
    console.log(this.test_prop3);
    console.log(this.test_prop4);
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you expecting `comp_data` values to change when you change the `testData` values?

Comment: Only initially when created is called on the parent. Afterwards it wont need any data from the parent. In the actual project I am trying to get the child to get it's initial data from the parent then set itself internally from that point on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `console.log` inside created hook will show you the initial state of this variables in Parent component. That's because Parent's created hook and Child's created hook will run at the same time.

So, when you solve your promise, Child component was already created. To understand this behavior, put your props in your template using `{{ this.test_prop }}`.

To solve it, depending on what you want, you can either define some **default value to your props** ([see](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html)) or render your child component with a **[v-if](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if) condition**. That's it, hope it helps!

Comment: Wow that actually worked. But I dont understand why. So if wrapped the child component in a v-if but let's say the api call takes 10 secs wont the v-if check have already happened so it just wont render the component and move on until the next rendering?

Comment: That's it! The created hook in Child is called just when v-if is true because v-if false doesn't render child component.

Comment: So I guess because im setting the child components initial data to whatever the prop is which will only happen after the api call is finished so it doesnt matter how long created hook takes? Am I understanding that right? Or does it matter because im using axios to make the call asynchronously and need to do this synchronously.

Comment: It depends on how you used v-if condition. I suggest bind it with a variable that will be true just **after** promise is solved. Doing it, no matter how much time your promise takes.

Answer (score 2):

On Vue created hook only the initial values of properties passed from main component. Therefore later updates (like your example "after ajax call") in main component  will not effect to child component data variables because of that already child **created hook take place.**
If you want to update data later one way you can do like this:

```
 watch: {
    test_prop: function(newOne){
      this.comp_data = newOne;
    }
 }
```

Adding **watcher** to property changes will update the last value of property from main component.

And also edit the typo `this.testDate3`. I guess it must be `this.testData3`

Comment: I use this approach either. Because of async props and `created` hook fired in a child component immediately after parent's `created`, so promise won't have a time to resolve yet. With a watcher, when it's resolved, you get the right data.