# Upload File to S3 bucket - vue-upload-component

Tags: amazon-s3, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to upload file to AWS S3 bucket using the [vue-upload-component](https://github.com/lian-yue/vue-upload-component). I have a web api set up which returns a pre-signed url with the relevant details. I am having a hard time getting this set up to work. The documentation says that the url should be supplied as a `props` to the file upload component like so -

```
:put-action="signedUrl" //local variable which is set to the url returned from the url
```

I am firing the web api call once the file passes the `inputFilter` filter criteria which in my case just checks for a text file extention. I am able to get the correct signed url which even works when I put the url as the value for the `put-action` props like so -

```
put-action="https://s3.amazonaws.com/...."
```

However, when trying to set it dynamically, the start upload status says - **No action configured** which is odd as I am sure the variable is being set after the promise is returned from the API.

So, it seems that the component is not accepting the new value.

I have tried to set the props after the promise is returned as suggested [here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/setting-props-using-code-as-well-as-markup/22300) and even tried to re render the upload component after promise is returned as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55515479/passing-data-to-props-after-asynchronous-call-in-vue) but still I am getting the same message.

What might be wrong with my approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get this working by setting the file level property [`putAction`](https://lian-yue.github.io/vue-upload-component/#/en/documents#instance-file-putaction)
like below -

```
methods: {    
inputFilter(newFile, oldFile, prevent) {
  if (newFile && !oldFile) {                
    if (doesNotPassTheFilter) {
      return prevent();
    }
    else {
      return this.$store.dispatch('getSignedUrl').then((url) => {            
        newFile.putAction = url;
      });
    }
  }
}
```